# Which class gets called first in a java project with many packages?

Tags: java

Is there a class called 'main' or something that java looks for in your project?

If it finds it, does the compiler take the 'main.class' as a starting point for compilation?

I don't know what to call my main class, whether there is even such a thing, or if more than one class act in tandem to control how the program works &/or call all the other classes.

I have a little experience in programming Minecraft mods, but that is also a bit scanty, so it would be awesome if you guys helped me out =]

Comment: Why didn't you google it?

Comment: Well, I did, got zilch and then remembered this great place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the JVM starts it will run a method named `main` with the signature:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

When you start the JVM you tell it which class to use to find the `main` method. Alternatively you can start the JVM with a jar file, in which case it will look at the manifest in order to determine which class's `main` method to use.

For the jar method you execute the JVM like `java -jar myjar.jar` and define the main class in the manifest file with the `Main-Class` attribute.

Otherwise you start the JVM like `java com.package.MyMainClass`

Answer (score 0):

At compilation time, it doesn't usually matter - you just specify all the source files you want to compile. (You *can* specify a subset and the compiler will find other source files it needs, but it's better to specify everything you want compiled.)

When you *execute* a Java program from the command line, you specify the class containing the `main` method:

```
java com.foo.MyAwesomeApp
```

Answer (score 0):

In runnable jar files, there should be META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file with Main-Class specified.